# Change resolution for specific application

Tags: windows, screen-resolution

On Microsoft Windows 11, is it possible to change the resolution of a single and specific application ?

Let's say that I have a 4k resolution. Some applications are readable, but some are really not. The fonts, the buttons, the images... are too small. I would be great to make the application bigger (like games can run in a different resolution).

Therefore I will not need to change the resolution down and up on a daily basis for just one program or two.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You cannot.

### Workaround

What you can do is make sure the application does not have an assembly manfiest that says it is `dpiAware`. Because even though it might have a manifest that says it is dpi aware: it obviously isn't.

Once the application is not `dpiAware`, you can scale your Windows to 125%, 150%, 200%, etc, and let **Windows** scale the application for you.

Comment: thanks appreciated. It's Ableton, can't find any manifest and can't find a way to scale the windows up

Comment: @YvesLange - _"can't find any manifest"_ - manifests are normally embedded as Win32 PE resources (rather than the filesystem), so you'll need a Win32 Resource Editor to extract it (but you can edit it in notepad). You can also use an external manifest file (a file in the same directory as the `.exe`) but I think embedded manifests override them by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests